# ConfuserEx - VS2019 - Obfuscating multiple project referenced in same solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, confuserex

I have two projects in my solution. The startup project is successfully able to obfuscate however, the other referenced project is not able to obfuscate successfully.

If I obfuscate individual projects separately in the same solution they are able to obfuscate but, then building the whole solution together gives build error for function(s) from other assemblies.

[image]

**The highlighted path is another project reference that is part of the same solution.**

Please suggest how I can resolve this error and make all the custom assemblies/projects obfuscate successfully?